# JavaFX How can I use one instance of scene in 2 windows? (Mirroring)

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I made a chess game that is supposed to run in 2 windows (stages). When a player moves a piece, in the second window the same piece moves accordingly. But the second window is rotated by 180 degrees to simulate a 2 player experience.

To realize this I thought it would be the easiest to use the 1 scene in 2 Windows. Basically a mirror of the first scene.

Problem: Figure doesn't move in the second window but the game knows that it has been moved in the first window because the player can't move the same figures again but the other color.

There is also a Main Menu, which has a play button, that starts the 2 windows.

```
    @FXML
    public void play_game(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
 Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("game_board.fxml")));
 Parent second_screen = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("game_board.fxml")));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        Stage second_stage = new Stage();
        second_stage.setScene(new Scene(second_screen));
        second_screen.rotateProperty().set(180);
        second_stage.show();
    }
```

The **controller class ** for the first window:

```
public class board_controller {
    @FXML
    GridPane chess_board;
    @FXML
    GridPane second_board;
    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        game_logic game_logic = new game_logic(chess_board);
    }
```

The controller class for the second window:

```
public class second_board_controller extends board_controller {

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        game_logic new_round = new game_logic(chess_board);
    }
}
```

My question is: How can I use the same exact instance of the scene but only rotated in the second window (Basically a Mirror of the first window)?

[Game Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjPGn.jpg)

Thank you!

I tried making the gridpane in the first_board controller static using it in the second board controller with the hopes of them updating automatically but with no results. Setting the main scene in first and second stages but my IDE said it's not allowed. I'm out of ideas...

Answer (score 3):

## Share the Model

Since you want to mirror between two windows in the same process, the general idea is to create two instances of your view but share only one instance of the model. The model should be observable in some way so that the view/controller can react to changes in the model by updating the view. With the model being shared and observed, updating it from one window will be seen by the other window.

### Models

Note a model should not know about the view. In your code, you do:

> ```java
> game_logic game_logic = new game_logic(chess_board);
> ```

From the name of the class, this indicates you're passing a `GridPane` (the view) to your model. It would be better if your model only *modelled* a chess game. The controller/view is responsible for translating that state into a visual representation.

### Rotating the Second View

The simplest approach to this would be to add state/a method to your controller, and then only on the second instance of the controller configure it to rotate the view. It is at least somewhat justifiable to put this logic in the controller/view because it is only a view thing (it does not affect the game state).

Though instead of rotating the board, you might want to consider "inverting" the location of the pieces (vertically). In other words, for the second view, have it so that a white piece in the bottom-left corner of the board is actually *displayed* in the top-left corner (and the opposite for black pieces). That way the chess piece images are not rotated along with the rest of the board.

---

## Example

Here's a proof-of-concept for mirroring a draggable rectangle (much simpler than a chess game). Note it only demonstrates the mirroring, it does not show how to e.g., rotate the view in one window but not the other.

`RectangleModel.java`:

```java
package sample;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class RectangleModel {

    private final List<Consumer<? super Dimensions>> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    private Dimensions dimensions;

    public RectangleModel(Dimensions dimensions) {
        this.dimensions = Objects.requireNonNull(dimensions);
    }

    public RectangleModel(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        this(new Dimensions(x, y, width, height));
    }

    public void move(double deltaX, double deltaY) {
        if (deltaX != 0.0 || deltaY != 0.0) {
            double x = dimensions.x() + deltaX;
            double y = dimensions.y() + deltaY;
            double w = dimensions.width();
            double h = dimensions.height();
            dimensions = new Dimensions(x, y, w, h);
            notifyListeners();
        }
    }

    public Dimensions getDimensions() {
        return dimensions;
    }

    public void addDimensionsListener(Consumer<? super Dimensions> listener) {
        listeners.add(Objects.requireNonNull(listener));
    }

    public void removeDimensionsListener(Consumer<? super Dimensions> listener) {
        listeners.remove(Objects.requireNonNull(listener));
    }

    private void notifyListeners() {
        for (var listener : listeners) {
            listener.accept(dimensions);
        }
    }

    public record Dimensions(double x, double y, double width, double height) {}
}
```

`RectangleController.java`:

```java
package sample;

import java.util.function.Consumer;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class RectangleController {

    private final Consumer<RectangleModel.Dimensions> listener = this::updateRectangle;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle rectangle;
    private Point2D offset;

    private RectangleModel model;

    public void setModel(RectangleModel model) {
        if (this.model != null) {
            this.model.removeDimensionsListener(listener);
        }

        this.model = model;
        if (model != null) {
            model.addDimensionsListener(listener);
            updateRectangle(model.getDimensions());
        } else {
            updateRectangle(null);
        }
    }

    private void updateRectangle(RectangleModel.Dimensions dims) {
        if (dims != null) {
            rectangle.setX(dims.x());
            rectangle.setY(dims.y());
            rectangle.setWidth(dims.width());
            rectangle.setHeight(dims.height());
        } else {
            rectangle.setX(0);
            rectangle.setY(0);
            rectangle.setWidth(0);
            rectangle.setHeight(0);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleMousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        event.consume();
        offset = new Point2D(event.getX(), event.getY());
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleMouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
        event.consume();

        double deltaX = event.getX() - offset.getX();
        double deltaY = event.getY() - offset.getY();
        model.move(deltaX, deltaY);

        offset = new Point2D(event.getX(), event.getY());
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleMouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        event.consume();
        offset = null;
    }
}
```

`RectangleView.fxml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>

<Pane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/"
      fx:controller="sample.RectangleController">
  <Rectangle fx:id="rectangle" onMousePressed="#handleMousePressed" onMouseDragged="#handleMouseDragged"
             onMouseReleased="#handleMouseReleased"/>
</Pane>
```

`Main.java`:

```java
package sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        var model = new RectangleModel(0, 0, 100, 50);

        primaryStage.setScene(createScene(model));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Primary Stage");
        primaryStage.show();

        var secondStage = new Stage();
        secondStage.setScene(createScene(model));
        secondStage.setTitle("Second Stage");
        secondStage.show();

        primaryStage.setX(primaryStage.getX() - primaryStage.getWidth() / 2);
        secondStage.setX(primaryStage.getX() + primaryStage.getWidth());
        secondStage.setY(primaryStage.getY());

        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> secondStage.close());
        secondStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> primaryStage.close());
    }

    private Scene createScene(RectangleModel model) throws IOException {
        var loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("RectangleView.fxml"));

        var root = loader.<Parent>load();
        var controller = loader.<RectangleController>getController();

        var scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        controller.setModel(model);
        return scene;
    }
}
```

---

## Naming Conventions

You should follow the standard naming conventions of Java (or whatever language you're using) when posting on a public forum.

- Classes and interfaces use `PascalCase`.
- Methods, fields, parameters, and local variables use `camelCase`.
- Static constants use `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`.